# Как быстро собрать базу данных?

Tags: парсер

Нужно собрать базу данных (Название компании, вид деятельности, телефон, e-mail)с сайтов каталогов предприятий. Для этого нужно писать парсер под каждый сайт? или можно написать универсальный парсер, который сможет парсить любые сайты-каталоги предприятий?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря какой размах проблемы. Если каталогов один два, то проще индивидуальные парсеры.

Если сайтов много и прибавляется, то гляньте на [Томита Парсер](http://api.yandex.ru/tomita/)

Ну и само собой не вздумайте html парсить руками, гуглите, инструментов куча